# How to determine the following sets (ex a ∪ {∅})

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Help! I don't know how to determine the  following sets

The question was: Let A={∅,{∅},{{∅}}. Determine the following sets

- a∪{∅}
- a∩{∅}
- a∩{{∅},{∅,{∅}}}
- a∪{{∅},{∅,{∅}}}

Comment: What is $a$ here?

Comment: These appear to resemble how natural numbers are defined...  Assuming $a,b$ are natural numbers defined using [Von Neumann construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), you have $a\cup b$ where $a,b$ are interpreted as sets has the same result as $\max(a,b)$ where $a,b$ are interpreted normally as numbers in the intuitive sense.  Similarly $a\cap b$ where $a,b$ are interpreted as sets has the same result as $\min(a,b)$ where $a,b$ are interpreted normally as numbers in the intuitive sense.

Comment: For the general case... it may help you to remember that the elements inside of your sets *are elements*.  For example, rather than looking at $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ as normal, think of it as the two element set $\{x,y\}$ where it just so happens that $x$ and $y$ have complicated representations and are sets themselves.

Answer (score 1):

a∪{∅} = a if ∅ in a.
Otherwise it is a with the additional element ∅.

a∩{∅} = {∅} if ∅ in a.  Otherwise it is empty set.